# How to print in Windows (Vista) using a different user?

Tags: windows, printing, user-accounts, network-printer, lpr

Is it possible to print as different user in Windows (Vista) without switching user?
I don't want to create profile for another user. (I need this because of some printers that are accessible only through LPR.)

Answer (score 0):

As you're LPRing, you could just use the "Run As" feature (although it'd be more practical to launch the the command prompt as the other user, and run your LPR commands from there.)

Comment: You mean run whole application (e.g. Open Office) using "Run As" or is it possible to setup somewhere (e.g. in registry) to always print using this printer as another user?

Comment: When you said you print via LPR, I thought you meant you actually use the command line LPR tool. If you're using a differing tool, then you could contact the vendor to see if they support connecting to the LPD server as a differing user, but otherwise you are going to have to run the whole application as the other user.